# glib: No iconv() implementation found in C library or libiconv

Tags: macos, glib, libiconv

I am trying to build a multilibrary project [cogl-3d](https://github.com/rib/cogl-android-sdk) and have found problems building glib.

After several fixes of gsid and more I've come to a halting point while trying to compile glib as no libiconv is found.

> checking for python script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>
> checking for python extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>
> checking for libiconv_open in -liconv... no
>
> configure: error: *** No iconv() implementation found in C library or libiconv

I have already trying installing, uninstalling and reinstalling the macports version, link with brew and adding /usr/libs to $PATH but none seems to work.